# Random string in end of my NFT collection

Tags: solidity, nft, opensea

I am new to NFT development. I have deployed a NFT contract to mumbai testnet and minted an NFT but I don't know what is this random string in the end of my Collection name
[image]

Does anyone know what is this `h27O3W97EA` string signifies and how to remove it?

Contract link: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xaE6FC519e26212A8de9F5F7eFdCE1d7B63a5547B

Contract:

```
// Contract based on https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc721
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract TestDemoNFT is ERC721URIStorage {
   using Counters for Counters.Counter;
   Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

   constructor() ERC721("Test Demo", "TNFT") {}

   function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
       public
       returns (uint256)
   {
       _tokenIds.increment();

       uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
       _mint(recipient, newItemId);
       _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

       return newItemId;
   }
}
```

Comment: it'd help if you post link to the contract in a blockchain explorer

Comment: It would help if you could post your contract here, or verify it on polygonscan. But I think it's just a randomly generated name by opensea. You can edit it from your collection profile.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I have added the contract and link of it above